# why is coinbase api returning an error while the code was working fine?

Tags: node.js, coinbase-api

i was using the above code to interact with coinbase api.it was working fine but until lately it returns an error.Here is the code

```
var coinbase = require('coinbase');
var mysecret = 'apisecret'
var mykey = 'apikey'
var client   = new coinbase.Client({'apiKey': mykey, 'apiSecret': mysecret});
client.getAccounts({}, function(err, accounts) {
   if (err)throw err;
    console.log(accounts)

});
```

here is the error i get

```
if (err)throw err
           ^

Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1058:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:636:8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coinbase have updated SSL certificates, to circumvent this, you will need to set `strictSSL` to `false` when you create a new client

```
const coinbase = require('coinbase')

const mysecret = 'apisecret'
const mykey = 'apikey'

const client = new coinbase.Client({ apiKey: mykey, apiSecret: mysecret, strictSSL: false })

client.getAccounts({}, function(err, accounts) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(accounts)
})
```

or pass in the new certificates

```
const coinbase = require('coinbase')

const mysecret = 'apisecret'
const mykey = 'apikey'
const caFile = fs.readFileSync('./caFileLocation')

const client = new coinbase.Client({ apiKey: mykey, apiSecret: mysecret, caFile })

client.getAccounts({}, function(err, accounts) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(accounts)
})
```